# Laplace transform of derivative

Tags: signal-analysis, laplace-transform

Here is a short proof that Laplace Transform of $x'(t)$ is Laplace transform of $x(t)$ multiplied by s:

[image]

On the other hand, the proof that I know uses integration by parts:

[image]

One condition for the second proof is that $x(t)e^{-st}$ decays to zero as $|t|$ goes to $\infty$

Why does the second proof require this condition while the first proof doesn't require any?

Answer (score 1):

The existence of $\mathcal L\{x*\delta'\}=\mathcal L\{x\}\cdot\mathcal L\{\delta'\}$ requires the same subexponential behaviour from $x$ (if $\lim_{|t|\to\infty}xe^{-st} \ne 0$, then $\mathcal L \{x\}$ doesn't exist). So, that's not a weaker requirement.